# UWP: InAppNotification not showing up

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to use the InAppNotification control from Windows Community Toolkit Sample App and have the code as below

```
<Grid>
    <tk_ctl:InAppNotification
            x:Name="InAppNotification"
            ShowDismissButton="True"
            Width="252.5"
            Content="In App Notification example"
            StackMode="Replace"/>
</Grid>
```

However, when i run the app, i dont see a pop up of any sort . Am i missing something ? Also is it possible to customize the InAppNotiifcation such that the dismiss button is at the top ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [InAppNotification.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.inappnotification.show?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) method to show your notification.

If you want to customize the `InAppNotification`, you could use the override `InAppNotification.Show(DataTemplate, Int32)` which specifying a `DataTemplate` as the content of the notification.

You could check the following code as a sample:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate">
        <UserControl>
            <Grid>
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonsStackPanel" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button x:Name="YesButton" Content="Confirm" Width="100" Height="32"  />
                        <Button x:Name="NoButton" Content="Dismiss" Width="100" Height="32" Margin="10 0 0 0"  />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="Do you Confirm it?" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <tk_ctl:InAppNotification x:Name="InAppNotification" ShowDismissButton="True"
                      Content="In App Notification example"
                              VerticalOffset="100"
                              HorizontalOffset="0"
                      StackMode="Replace">
    </tk_ctl:InAppNotification>

</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
……
object inAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate;
bool isTemplatePresent = Resources.TryGetValue("InAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate", out inAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate);
if(isTemplatePresent&&inAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate is DataTemplate)
{
    InAppNotification.Show(inAppNotificationWithButtonsTemplate as DataTemplate);
}
```